# How to export the current wpa_cli network to a file?

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, wpa-cli

Say I have connected with `wpa_cli` to a network `mynetwork`:

```
# wpa_cli 
>add_network
>set_network 0 ssid "mynetwork"
>set_network 0 psk "SupahSecretPassphrase"
>enable_network 0
>reconnect
```

**How to export this network to a wpa_supplicant configuration file, that is a file containing**:

```
network={
               ssid="mynetwork"
               psk="SupahSecretPassphrase"
          }
```

If there is no standard way, I guess I would have to recall `~/.wpa_cli_history`

---

PS:

I tried `save_config` but I always have a FAIL result:

```
>  save_config
FAIL
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add `update_config=1` to your configuration file , it will give the rights to update it.

there is an example :

edit the `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_example.conf` , add the following lines:

```
ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

Run `wpa_passphrase` command to export your configuration to `wpa_supplicant_example.conf`

```
wpa_passphrase Your_ssid Your_passphrase >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant_example.conf
```

Save then connect through `wpa_cli`.

Comment: Honestly I still get the FAIL error when trying to `save_config`, following these steps didn't work to me.

Comment: @roizpi Did you have NetworkManger installed? Did you have a wired connection available to reinstall it later if something went wrong ? If YES remove it.

Comment: I haven't networkmanager installed. I have the wired connection yes, and wlan1 seems to have access point associated, but when disconecting the wire, I can't find any host associated with that machine.

Comment: @roizpi Check the status `wpa_cli status` disconnect `wpa_cli disconnect` then try to reconnect. Remove the RJ45 first.

Comment: I made the network work by using your steps, and making a proper configuration of `/etc/network/interfaces`. Thank you.